# log4j issue in ear project deployed in weblogic

Tags: log4j, weblogic, ear

I have configured `log4j` in resources folder of each module in EAR project. EAR contains two WARs and one EJB and one JAR. I deployed EAR in Weblogic which is running in cluster mode.
`log4j` is not working in Weblogic cluster node.

Comment: Please define "not working" and what is "resources folder"?

Answer (score 0):

Log4j requires log4j.properties/log4j.xml for proper configuration. When Log4j loads it looks for either log4j.properties file or log4j.xml. If log4j is not able to locate this file
it will not log at all.

In order to make log4j to work make sure

1. Log4j.properties/log4j.xml file is in classpath.
2. All modules/jars/ejbs/war must use the same property/xml file unless otherwise
     you need separate log4j configurations for each module.
3. More than one configuration files either property file or xml will conflict and log4j  may will not work as expected.